# Unramified cubic extension of imaginary quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $ K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-m})$ be an imaginary quadratic field with class number  $ 6.$ Then by Hilbert class field theory and Galois correspondence it is known that $ K$ has a unramified cubic extension. Is there any  explicit way to find out unramified cubic extension of quadratic fields.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you didn’t ask this question for class number $3$?

Comment: Mr. Lubin I thought if class number is $ 3$ then unramified cubic extension is  same as Hilbert class field of $ K$. Am I correct?

Comment: then in the case of class number $6$, can’t you take the requisite Hilbert class field and the unique subfield that’s a cubic extension of $K$?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Lubin still I am having some doubt how to write explicitly what is the cubic unrmified extension of $ K.$

Comment: Aha, but that was exactly why I wasn’t too happy with your remark about class number $3$. Can you “write down” the Hilbert class field in either case? If you can, it should not be too hard to perform the last step in the case of class number $6$.

Comment: Actually I am trying to construct unramified cubic extension of imaginary quadratic fields. Is there any criteria to show that $K(\sqrt[3]{\alpha})$ is unramified cubic extension? As I know criteria for unramified quadratic extension $K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ where $ \alpha$ is not a square, $ \langle\alpha\rangle$ is square of an ideal, $ \alpha$ totally positive.

Comment: Also, $ \alpha\equiv 1\mbox{(mod}~4). $

Comment: I don’t think that you can expect that your cubic extension will be gotten by adjoining a cube root. You would need $\omega$, a primitive cube root of unity, to be in your smaller field expect that.

Comment: What does it mean? I did not get your point? Does it mean that any imaginary quadratic number fields with class number multiple of $ 3$ will not have unramified cubic extensions?

Comment: it means that your cubic extension $K\supset k$ may not be of the form $K=k(\alpha^{1/3})$, that’s all I was saying. Indeed, any time that $k(\alpha^{1/3})$ is Galois over $k$, you must have $\omega\in K$, and I don’t believe that this is the case in most of the situations we’re talking about, since $3$ is not ramified in $K$.

Comment: related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476830/ring-class-field-of-mathbbq-sqrt-19/477194#477194

Answer (score 2):

Let $L = K(\sqrt{-3})$; then your cubic extension $H/K$ becomes a Kummer extension $HL = L(\sqrt[3]{\alpha})$. The proofs of classical class field theory show that 
$\alpha$ can be chosen as a generator of an ideal ${\mathfrak a}^3$, where
${\mathfrak a}$ generates an ideal class of order $3$ in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{3m})$.
You have to pick the generator $\alpha$ in such a way that the cubic extension becomes unramified (the condition is something like $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod 3\sqrt{-3}$ if memory serves). See Thm. 1.5.1 over [here](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/pcft.pdf).